# TypeInitializationException when instaling CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have made a Web Api app and I want to access this api from a separate
website using Ajax.

To access the api I need to install CORS, but when doing so I get the 
error (when Debuging):

> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in MvcApplication1.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration' threw an exception**

This error occurs within Global.asax.cs at:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

After rebuilding the solution and Debuging it again, I get navigatet to the webpage wich then show another error message:

> Cannot create/shadow copy 'EntityFramework' when that file already exists.**

The Web Api worked perfect before I installed CORS, other than not
be able to access the api from a another website/location, witch is what I want...

Answer (score 4):

The release candidate it should fix the error. Open the package mangaer console and copy/paste the below command.

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -IncludePrerelease`